# How to set the startup directory in Git Bash?

Tags: git, git-bash, working-directory

What is the command to set startup directory in Git Bash?

When I start Git Bash, the startup directory is Bitbust directory in C drive, so I must change the working directory with `cd` command.

But I think it is an unnecessary process. I want the startup directory to be my working directory where Git Bash is started.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right click on the shortcut, and select properties. Navigate to the "shortcut" tab.

There are two things you need to change here. First, by default, the Target field will end in `--cd-to-home` - remove it. Once you've done that, you can edit the `Start in` field and give it any directory you want.

E.g., this is how the shortcut looks on my machine:

[image]

After editing, you'll have:

[image]

You could also, of course, create multiple Git Bash shortcuts to start in each directory you're interested in.

Comment: I tried as your help but startup directory is still c:/users/my username?
What is the reason?

Comment: @JohnMiller are you **sure** you remove the `--cd-to-home`?

Comment: Shortcut property is property of Git Bush shortcut on the desktop?

Comment: @JohnMiller yes. Unless you're launching it in another way, in which case you'll have to edit that shortcut instead.

Comment: What is the purpose of `--cd-to-home` ?  Removing it and setting the directory worked but I was curious why `--cd-to-home` needs removed.

Comment: @rich `--cd-to-home` causes Git Bah to change directory to your home directory after it starts, making the "start in" directory kind of pointless. Removing this flag makes it stay in the directory it was opened in.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick fix;

Instead of opening git and navigating to the folder you want by using 
cd /long/path/to/your/files do as below;

In Windows 10,

- Go to any folder you like.
- Right click
- Click Open Git here
- Then Git will automatically open in the selected folder.

[Here is how it looks when you right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlUKy.png)

Comment: Thank you; I don't remember if I've ever customized a Git Bash path on Windows, but you made it really, really easy.  I used your protip to set up my most-often-worked-on-repository!  Again, thank you!

Comment: It didn't work for me. I wonder why it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach (If always working from a single folder) to achieve the same result

1. create a file in user directory (for windows, mostly it is in `c\users\<username>\`) named as `.bashrc`
2. add content as the `cd` command with the desired folder location, as in `cd /d/dev/my-project`